# ubuntu sudo service mongod status shows failed but mongo is working

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongoid

I started a replica set with three servers with default port and used a different data directory. But when i did sudo service mongod stop. it said failed. so i went into mongo shell and did a shutdown and mongo shell stopped working. now when i did sudo service mongod start it said failed but i was able to go to mongo shell and the reolica set was working. I checked sudo service mongod status it said failed.

```
sudo service mongod status
[FAIL] Checking status of database: mongod apparently not running failed!
```

i edited mongod.config to have a replica set name , commented out bind_ip, used keyfile for auth

Comment: Which version of MongoDB did you install? Did you use the 10gen repo or the Ubuntu packages? Please let me remind you that Stackoverflow is aimed at _programming_ questions, making your question off topic here. Please ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com _or_ http://www.serverfault.com, complemented by the information I requested and delete here.

Comment: posted it in dbstack exchange:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83466/debian-sudo-service-mongod-status-shows-failed-but-mongo-is-working